# iPhone: Control to Change Date (Besides Picker)

Tags: iphone

The iPhone Calendar app has a control on top that allows you to change the date from today to yesterday or tomorrow... Does the iPhone API come with this control for free, or do I have to implement it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no predefined item.  It looks like a uiToolbar with two buttons (unicode arrows) and a label.

Answer (score 0):

try kal on github. It doesn't have all these features, but will serve you well as a date picker.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it yourself. On the face of it, it looks pretty simple: just two UILabels (weekday and date) and two buttons, and a background image. You might even be able to put it together with an appropriately tinted UIToolbar and some UIBarButtonItems initialized with `initWithCustomView:`.